# App Part Correlation ID - How to retrieve error details?

Tags: sharepoint-online, app-part

I am a tenant on SharePoint Online. I have deployed a basic Add In with an app part included. The app installs fine, but when I try add the App Part to a page I get this:
[image]

How can I get the details of the error? I've read [this](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/view-tenant-uls-logs-in-sharepoint.html) and have created the console app. However, when I substitute in my correlation ID, I am not getting anything back. The console app runs fine, just no output.

[image]
[image]

I know I could probably debug this through Visual Studio by disabling sideloading, but I'd like to know how I can get the error details without having to do this, as it won't be allowed in our production environments.

Comment: can you provide more details from log file using correlation ID.

Comment: That's what I'm asking... how do I retrieve the details? With on-prem I would have access to the ULS logs, but on SharePoint Online you don't.